# Inventory management with limited time hold strategy - How do I protect from bad actors?

Tags: design, concurrency, e-commerce, locks

Some sites, like theater ticket reservations, place a limited-time hold on the item , while the order is being processed. As soon as you select the seat and proceed to pay, Seat is reserved say for 10 minutes.

I see here a big risk where a hacker/automated script(bot)/manual user can lock all inventory and does not actually make the payment. He keeps on repeating
this process. This way seats will never be booked and  business will loose the revenue.

How these sites handle this scenario/challenge ?

Comment: The way sites like Ticketmaster deal with bots is no different than how any other site deals with them.  The most common and effective technique is using reCaptcha.

Comment: @RobertHarvey leave bots, what about regular users  who can lock the inventory and may cause inventory out of stock ?

Comment: They would have to do that by hand, one ticket at a time, and I would imagine you could limit them to, say, 10 requests per IP per hour.  You want to go to the expense of setting up a human farm to accomplish this?  Go right ahead.

Comment: Consider a competitor_company_B who wants  company_A does not get revenue  and creates 50 login account . Before 1 hour movie show(which is peak time), books 10 seat (does not make payment), keeps on doing it for 1 hour from different account. Whether it is practical or not, its different matter. But question is how system/website can be protected from this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

I really have no idea what various sites do, but its easy enough to dream up an algorithm to make it hard for fake customers or bots.

Include a test that most AI's find difficult (like reCaptcha as Robert Harvey suggests). This should eliminate the bots.

Then a procedure something like this...

1. Person A books item I
2. Create provisional order for "Item I" with name/IP of person ordering.

   Request Person A to complete payment.
3. If there are more requests for item I, while order is processing,advise customer that the item is on hold for another user and optionally place them in a queue. Discard any additional orders from person A.
4. If person A pays on time,

   ```
   Remove item I from stock and empty the queue for that item.
   Inform queued customers that item I is sold and offer alternatives.
   ```
5. If Person A did not pay on time.

   ```
   Go back to step 2 and start processing the next person in the queue.
   ```

If there is no demand for Item A, then who cares if mean old Person A likes to waste his time re-ordering and not paying!

Comment: @user3198603 If this is off the mark just down vote and I will delete. Otherwise up vote!